# En Jquery+Bootstrap cómo validar que en un elemento Select múltiple se ha seleccionado por lo menos una opción

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Antes de enviar los datos de un formulario, necesito validar que todos los datos requeridos hayan sido ingresado o seleccionado. Tengo varios input y dos elementos select, uno admite una selección de un sólo elemento. El otro select es múltiple, por lo que admite más de una selección de elementos.

El primer Select está definido así:

```
<select id="tipocompra" name="tipocompra[]" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" title="Seleccione tipo Compra">
```

Para validar que este "Select" tenga un elemento seleccionado, lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
if($("#tipocompra").val().trim() === '')
```

El segundo Select, está definido de la siguiente forma:

```
<select id="tipofondo" name="tipofondo[]" class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count" title="Seleccione el fondo" data-style="btn-info">
```

Al tratar de validar de que este Select tiene al menos un elemento seleccionado, hago lo mismo que en el caso anterior:

```
if($("#tipofondo").val().trim() === '')
```

Pero me arroja el error en la consola:

```
ingsol.php:119 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).trim is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ingsol.php:119)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

La única deiferencia entre los dos Select, es que el último es "multiple" y por ende, no funciona.

Cómo debería implementarse la validación de que se haya seleccionado al menos un elemento en un Select múltiple?? Gracias y buen día.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta hacerlo de esta forma:

Les dejaré un ejemplo que hice yo mismo, primero el archivo JS y seguido el HTML (probadlo cambiando un valor relleno por el vacío):

```js
$(() => $("#id_select").change(() => $("#id_select").val().trim() === "" ? $("#mostrar").html("<h1>No hay datos</h1>") : $("#mostrar").html("<h1>Hay datos</h1>")));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="file.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <select name="oficio" id="id_select">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="oficio1">Oficio 1</option>
        <option value="oficio2">Oficio 2</option>
        <option value="oficio3">Oficio 3</option>
        <option value="oficio4">Oficio 4</option>
        <option value="oficio5">Oficio 5</option>
        <option value="oficio6">Oficio 6</option>
    </select>
    <div id="mostrar"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

ACLARACIÓN:
En los select solo meterás datos con los "value" que tu definas, por lo que ya sabes que se lanzarán normalmente esos valores, no obstante la gente intentará hacer cosas no muy buenas en la página por lo que te recomiendo que hagas una validación en JS más compleja y que la validación también vaya al servidor, ya que alguien le puede pasar un valor 0 y a lo mejor en la aplicación que vayas a hacer es un problema. Si es una web profesional haz una validación más profunda, que con AJAX estos agujeros de seguridad se solucionan (al menos muchos de ellos).

Si no he entendido bien el ejercicio agradecería que me lo dijeses para poder solucionarlo si siguiesen quedando dudas. Por cierto, estos problemas de validación de campos vacíos tienen múltiples soluciones con js, en caso de querer ver otra posible solución la diré sin problemas.

Comment: kmevi, mucha gracias por tus sugerencias. Con respecto de los temas de hoyos de seguridad que mencionas , por favor, me puedes indicar algunos tips a tener en cuenta con respecto de problemas de seguridad que hay que tener en cuenta cuando se implementan soluciones; te estaré muy agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Funciona con:

```
if($("#tipofondo").val().length<1){
```